# Multiple icons in dock?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, dock

Is it possible to have multiple icons open for multiple instances of an application? For example, if I have two pdf's open, can I have two "preview" icons open in the doc bar?

Answer (score 3):

You can open multiple instances of a mac application using `open -n` terminal command. Eg. `open -n image2.pdf`

[More information](http://www.macworld.com/article/1158007/opentwoinstancesofoneapp.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because I have to do that quite often : Yes, it is indeed possible and it makes use of the command provided in the answer by kekub.

Just create an application with Automator: 
1) Open Automator 
2) Choose "Application" 
3) Search for the Shell-Script workflow element 
4) Change the Input to "As Arguments" 
5) Adjust the Shell script like this :

```
    for f in "$@"
    do
        open -a preview -n "$f"
    done
```

6) Save the Programm as Something like "Preview+" 
7) Optional :  Change the default application for images to this created app 
8) Optional : Move it to the dock and drop images on it.

Now for each Image there will be a new instance of Preview.

You can do that with every app you like.

Comment: Nice! I will try this out when I get home.